# Deploying Mahout on hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop, cluster-analysis, k-means, mahout

I want to run Mahout's K-Means example in a hadoop cluster of 5 machines. Which Mahout jar files should I need to keep in all the nodes, in order for the K-Means to be executed in a distributed manner. 
Thanks.

-Venkiram

Answer (score 2):

If you really just want to run the built-in K-Means, or other jobs with static drivers, the answer is 'none'. The mahout 'job' jars are self-contained hadoop job jars. If you submit a job to the cluster with 'hadoop job' it will work without any other jars.

Comment: Thanks. I have installed Mahout jars in master node, should I replicate it in all slave nodes also?

Comment: Now you are beyond what I know about hadoop.

Comment: Isn't the job driver supposed to take care of this by localizing the .jar on all the nodes it uses?